# How can I sort x axis values (month-year) on ggplot2 bar plot correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame which contains the following columns: J (year), M (month), Monat (which is composed as M-J), and two other variables which contain name and a month sum.
The column Monat (M-J) should go to the x-axis, and the month sum onto the y-axis. The name is used as category.

As with M-J, the ordering on the x-axis is not correct. How can I get the ordering based on M and J correct?

I tried converting M and J to factors, played with reorder, but I could not get it right.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_cre <- data.frame(J=c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                         2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
                         2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 
                         2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
                         2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 
                         2023, 2023, 2023, 2023), 
                     M=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                       11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 
                       1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
                       12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5), 
                     Wer=c("Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", 
                      "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", 
                      "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", 
                      "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", 
                      "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", 
                      "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", 
                      "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", 
                      "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt2"), 
                     Einnahmen=c(20265.43, 
                       9323.48, 3350.52, 3338.37, 3317.05, 7223.91, 4632.8, 23264.63, 
                       3678.72, 3374.29, 8290, 8176.53, 7805.57, 3276.87, 3490.59, 
                       3189.03, 3189.72, 7115.97, 3183.22, 3182.24, 3475.89, 3343.2, 
                       203.71, 8095.84, 599.64, 3214.26, 639.52, 3567.89, 509.28, 
                       7327.42, 644.01, 3452.29, 3623.8, 3363.84, 7580.19, 3975.35, 
                       1913, 3796.32, 1110, 3765.24, 1110, 3976.99, 1110, 7542.8, 
                       1549, 3529.44, 3451.7, 3476.97, 3495.02, 4110.98, 485.48, 
                       447.02), 
                     Monat=c("1-2020", "2-2020", "3-2020", "4-2020", "5-2020", 
                      "6-2020", "7-2020", "8-2020", "9-2020", "10-2020", "11-2020", 
                      "12-2020", "1-2021", "2-2021", "3-2021", "4-2021", "5-2021", 
                      "6-2021", "7-2021", "8-2021", "9-2021", "10-2021", "10-2021", 
                      "11-2021", "11-2021", "12-2021", "12-2021", "1-2022", "1-2022", 
                      "2-2022", "2-2022", "3-2022", "4-2022", "5-2022", "6-2022", 
                      "7-2022", "7-2022", "8-2022", "8-2022", "9-2022", "9-2022", 
                      "10-2022", "10-2022", "11-2022", "11-2022", "12-2022", "1-2023", 
                      "2-2023", "3-2023", "4-2023", "5-2023", "5-2023"))

df_cre %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=Wer, y=Einnahmen, x=Monat)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  #scale_x_discrete(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n=10)) 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

I flipped the coordinates as the x-axis is very dense. This is a problem for later :)

[image: bar plot with wrong ordering on x-axis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
df_cre=df_cre |> mutate(date=my(Monat))
df_cre %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=Wer, y=Einnahmen, x=date)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_x_date(breaks="5 month", labels = date_format("%b-%y"))
```

[image]

Comment: fyi `coord_flip` mostly unnecessary since ggplot 3.3.0 in March 2020, you can in most cases just specify the x and y you want, and use `orientation` if there is any ambiguity. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#bi-directional-geoms-and-stats

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the dodged M-YYYY y axis:

```
df_cre %>% 
  mutate(Monat = forcats::fct_reorder(
    Monat, lubridate::my(Monat)) %>% forcats::fct_rev()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Einnahmen, y=Monat, fill=Wer)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, two more solutions while I fiddled around with the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I managed to get it working, by introducing a new column which holds the first day of a month, and then using `scale_x_date` to get a label on the x-axis:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_cre <- 
  data.frame(Monat=c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", 
               "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", 
               "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", 
               "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", "2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", 
               "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", "2021-10-01", "2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", 
               "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", 
               "2022-02-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", 
               "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", "2022-07-01", "2022-08-01", "2022-08-01", 
               "2022-09-01", "2022-09-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-11-01", 
               "2022-11-01", "2022-12-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-02-01", "2023-03-01", 
               "2023-04-01", "2023-05-01", "2023-05-01"), 
             Wer=c("Abt1", "Abt1", 
              "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", 
              "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", 
              "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt2", 
              "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", 
              "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt2", 
              "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt1", 
              "Abt2", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", 
              "Abt2"), 
             Einnahmen=c(20265.43, 9323.48, 3350.52, 3338.37, 3317.05, 
              7223.91, 4632.8, 23264.63, 3678.72, 3374.29, 8290, 8176.53, 
              7805.57, 3276.87, 3490.59, 3189.03, 3189.72, 7115.97, 3183.22, 
              3182.24, 3475.89, 3343.2, 203.71, 8095.84, 599.64, 3214.26, 
              639.52, 3567.89, 509.28, 7327.42, 644.01, 3452.29, 3623.8, 
              3363.84, 7580.19, 3975.35, 1913, 3796.32, 1110, 3765.24, 
              1110, 3976.99, 1110, 7542.8, 1549, 3529.44, 3451.7, 3476.97, 
              3495.02, 4110.98, 485.48, 447.02))

df_cre$Monat <- as.Date(df_cre$Monat)

df_cre %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=Wer, y=Einnahmen, x=Monat)) + 
  geom_col(position="stack") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "3 month")
```

This gives the following plot:

[image: Plot with x-asis properly ordered]